# Android Firebase How can I get the userid of another child without logging to them?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Hello I'm trying to add information on **Transcations** while simultaneously upadting the **Date** on my **Users** child. But one problem I'm experiencing right now is that, I'm having a hard time getting the uid of user suuun@some.com. Is it perhaps possible to get it through their email? And how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not trying to be nosy, but the Doug Stevenson's answer is partially correct. As your are querying by email you have to iterate the child of dataSnapshot, otherwise the dataSnapshot.getKey() will always return "email" instead of uid.

This little detail sometimes goes unnoticed and already made me pluck my hair a few times.

Even knowing that your result will be only 1 you will have to iterate.

Take a look at it:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Accounts/Users");
Query query = reference.orderByChild("email").equalTo("suuun@some.com");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
         String uid = childSnapshot.getKey();
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Helllo I tried your method http://prntscr.com/il61v2 but for some reason its updating multiple users(not all) at the same time. Is there perhaps something wrogn with my code?

Comment: Humm ... I see ... there is an error on query. You have to use equalTo instead of startAt. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

[Use orderByChild()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sort_data) to find the records that match a child's value.

```
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Accounts/Users");
    Query query = reference.orderByChild("email").startAt("suuun@some.com");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // contains the matching record
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```